# Layout for Magento module

Tags: magento, layout

I'm new in Magento and I'm trying to make a layout for a module I've build. I have a simple module and an IndexController which outputs 'Hello World.'(I've use [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch) tutorial).

Now I want to make a layout for that module and I've used this [tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates) but it doesn't work. Can someone point me to a tutorial or can explain me how layouts work in Magento?

Thx :)

Here's what I've done so far:
I have a package called 'Andrei' and a module 'Hello World'.

Here is the config.xml for my module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Andrei_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Andrei_Helloworld>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Andrei_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Here is the Andrei_Helloworld module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Andrei_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Andrei_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And here is my controller:

```
class Andrei_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'Hello world';
    }
}
```

This is all I've done so far. The module works properly. And I want a layout for my IndexController. Thx :)

Comment: you should show us your code, mainly the config.xml, the xml layout file and your blocks php classes.

Comment: I've edited my question with my code :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

so, there is some stuff missing...

- declare the layout update in the your config.xml:

  ```
  <frontend>
      ...
      <layout>
          <updates>
              <helloworld>
                  <file>helloworld.xml</file>
              </helloworld>
          </updates>
      </layout>
      ...
  </frontend>
  ```
- create the layout xml file, in **app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/helloworld.xml** and in it you create a reference to your module/controller/action:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <layout>
      <helloworld_index_index>
          <reference name="content">
              <block type="core/template" name="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml" />
          </reference>
      </helloworld_index_index>
  </layout>
  ```
- create the phtml file you've just set as template in your xml layout file, ie **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/helloworld.phtml**:

  ```
  this is the content of helloworld.phtml
  ```
- load and render all this stuff, in your controller's action, replace your `echo` statement with:

  ```
  public function indexAction()
  {
      $this->loadLayout();
      $this->renderLayout();
  }
  ```
- disable cache, refresh browser, sit back and enjoy